# How do I get value from ACE editor without comments?

Tags: javascript, editor, ace-editor

Is it possible to get the value of an ace editor instance without the comments (single & multi row)? The comments are identified by the span class 'ace_comment', but the only function I found to extract the data is getValue().

Easy Example:

```
console.log("Hello World") //This is a comment.
```

What I get: 
  Output: 'console.log("Hello World") //This is a comment.'

What I want: 
  Output: 'console.log("Hello World")'

Extended Example (Multi-row + '//' and '/* */' comments):

*/ This is 
a comment */ console.log("this is not a comment") // comment again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to remove comments:

```js
var string = 'console.log("Hello World") //This is a comment. \n' + 
             'hello("foo"); /* This is also a comment. */';
string = string.replace(/\s*\/\/.*\n/g, '\n').replace(/\s*\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//g, '');
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + string + '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping that there would be a build in solution, but this seems to work fine.

Comment: @jcubic: It fails for `"/* remove\nthis multine\ncomment */RETURN 1"`. Is it possible to fix this, and also support unclosed multi-line comments (i.e. match up to `*/` or end of input)?

Comment: Updated the answer, use `[\s\S]*?` instead of `.*?`

Comment: `[\s\S]` is a very neat trick since there's no DOTALL modifier in JS! Here's a RegExp that seems to also cover some corner cases of my particular use case: `var t = "/* remove this\nmulti-line comment */FOR doc IN coll/*\n@ignore @me*/FILTER doc./**/attr = @val//delete me\nSORT doc.foo DESC\n// away with you /*\n<YOU MUST KEEP ME>\n//*/\nRETURN doc\n/* this is // replaced in two steps,\nbut in the end, it's all gone!\n*/\nLIMIT 1\n/* some old\nqueries go here"` **Remove the cruft:** `t.replace(/\s*\/\/.*\n/g, '\n').replace(/\/\*.*?\*\//g,"").replace(/\s*\/\*[\s\S]*?(\*\/|$)/g, '\n');`

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution will be. To just trim the //Comment like this

```js
    var str = 'console.log("HelloWorld")//This is a comment';
        str = str.split('//');

    //Just to print out
    document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>You provide > '+ str[0]+'//'+str[1] +'</pre><pre>Output > ' + str[0] + '</pre>';
```

By doing this you're spliting the the entire string by the '//' split returns an array that will have [0] = console.log('HelloWorld'); and the [1] = 'Comment like this'. This is the simplest solution i can think of. jcubic. Is basically doing the same by using a regex. Good look!

Comment: Sorry then I was not clear enough, I need to detect single-row comments and also multi-row comments as well as full row comments, and cuttet comments like e.g.:

*/ This is a comment */ console.log("this is not a comment") // comment again

Comment: I see well jcubic's' answer is what you need :)